# Find allele frequencies at each site for each iteration for each population from FASTA file

Tags: python, beginner, parsing, bioinformatics

The script takes a FASTA format file in input and outputs the frequencies of each amino acid (`A`, `C`, `T` and `G`) at each site per population per iteration. The name of each sequence looks like `>it0pop1ind0locus0`. In this example, this indicates that the sequence that follows is the DNA sequence for the zeroth iteration (`it`), the first population (`pop`), the zeroth individual (`ind`) at the zeroth locus (`locus`).

My goal (just to restate it) is to get the frequencies of each amino acid (`A`, `C`, `T` and `G`) at each site per population per iteration.

```
from __future__ import division
import os
from Bio import SeqIO
import itertools
import re
import sys
os.chdir("/path/to/directory/")

#### ReFormat the data ####

maxit = 1
maxpop = 1
maxind = 1
maxlocus = 1
for pos, i in enumerate(SeqIO.parse("0.0.1.fasta", "fasta")):
    if pos == 0:
        maxsite = len(i.seq)
    v1 = re.findall(r'\d+', i.id)
    v = []
    for val in v1:
        v.append(int(val))
    maxit = max(v[0]+1, maxit)
    maxpop = max(v[1]+1, maxpop)
    maxind = max(v[2]+1, maxind)
    maxlocus = max(v[3]+1, maxlocus)

all = [[[[ "x" * maxsite for locus in xrange(maxlocus)] for ind in xrange(maxind)] for pop in xrange(maxpop)] for it in xrange(maxit)]

for i in SeqIO.parse("0.0.1.fasta", "fasta"):
    v1 = re.findall(r'\d+', i.id)
    v = []
    for val in v1:
        v.append(int(val))
    it = v[0]
    pop = v[1]
    ind = v[2]
    locus = v[3]
    all[it][pop][ind][locus] = str(i.seq)

#### Calculate the frequencies ####

pA = [[[2 for it in xrange(maxsite)] for pop in xrange(maxpop)] for site in xrange(maxit)]
pC = [[[2 for it in xrange(maxsite)] for pop in xrange(maxpop)] for site in xrange(maxit)]
pG = [[[2 for it in xrange(maxsite)] for pop in xrange(maxpop)] for site in xrange(maxit)]
pT = [[[2 for it in xrange(maxsite)] for pop in xrange(maxpop)] for site in xrange(maxit)]

for it in xrange(maxit):
    for pop in xrange(maxpop):
        for locus in xrange(maxlocus):
            for site in xrange(maxsite):
                x = []
                for ind in xrange(maxind):
                    x.append(all[it][pop][ind][locus][site])
                pA[it][pop][site] = x.count("A")/maxind
                pT[it][pop][site] = x.count("T")/maxind
                pC[it][pop][site] = x.count("C")/maxind
                pG[it][pop][site] = x.count("G")/maxind
```

Here are the values I get:

> ```
> >>> pA
> [[[0.16666666666666666, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.6666666666666666, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0]]]
> >>> pC
> [[[0.8333333333333334, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.6666666666666666, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]]
> >>> pG
> [[[0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.3333333333333333, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]]
> >>> pT
> [[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.3333333333333333, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]]
> ```

---

Here is the data for the example (FASTA). In this example, we have only 1 iteration (`it`), 2 populations (`pop`), 5 individuals (`ind`), 1 locus (`locus`) and 9 sites (length of the sequence).

> ```
> >it0pop0ind0locus0
> CGGCAGAAC
> >it0pop0ind1locus0
> CGGCAGATC
> >it0pop0ind2locus0
> CGGCAGAAC
> >it0pop0ind3locus0
> CGGCAGAAC
> >it0pop0ind4locus0
> CGGCAGATC
> >it0pop0ind5locus0
> AGGCAGAAC
> >it0pop1ind0locus0
> CGGCAGAAC
> >it0pop1ind1locus0
> CGGCAGAAC
> >it0pop1ind2locus0
> CGGGAGAAC
> >it0pop1ind3locus0
> CGGCAGAAC
> >it0pop1ind4locus0
> CGGGAGAAC
> >it0pop1ind5locus0
> CGGCAGAAC
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**let me choose**

First things first; your code is `chdir`ing to `/path/to/directory/` and opening `0.0.1.fasta`. This is woefully inflexible.

The simplest fix is to accept an argument on the command line, as `sys.argv[1]`. (Don't use `chdir`.)

**numpy**

What you're doing looks a lil' bit crazy. To deal with highly-dimensional data, Numpy is often a good candidate.

A first-pass would look something like

```
from __future__ import division

import os
from Bio import SeqIO
import itertools
import re
import sys
import numpy

#### ReFormat the data ####

filename = sys.argv[1]

maxit = 1
maxpop = 1
maxind = 1
maxlocus = 1
for pos, i in enumerate(SeqIO.parse(filename, "fasta")):
    print(i.seq)

    if pos == 0:
        maxsite = len(i.seq)

    it, pop, ind, locus = [int(d) for d in re.findall(r'\d+', i.id)]

    maxit = max(it+1, maxit)
    maxpop = max(pop+1, maxpop)
    maxind = max(ind+1, maxind)
    maxlocus = max(locus+1, maxlocus)

all = numpy.full((maxit, maxpop, maxind, maxlocus, maxsite), '\0', dtype="S")

for i in SeqIO.parse(filename, "fasta"):
    it, pop, ind, locus = [int(d) for d in re.findall(r'\d+', i.id)]
    all[it, pop, ind, locus] = i.seq

print(all)
print("---")
#### Calculate the frequencies ####

pA = numpy.full((maxit, maxpop, maxsite), 2)
pC = numpy.full((maxit, maxpop, maxsite), 2)
pG = numpy.full((maxit, maxpop, maxsite), 2)
pT = numpy.full((maxit, maxpop, maxsite), 2)

for it in xrange(maxit):
    for pop in xrange(maxpop):
        for locus in xrange(maxlocus):
            for site in xrange(maxsite):
                x = []
                for ind in xrange(maxind):
                    x.append(all[it, pop, ind, locus, site])
                pA[it, pop, site] = x.count("A") / maxind
                pT[it, pop, site] = x.count("T") / maxind
                pC[it, pop, site] = x.count("C") / maxind
                pG[it, pop, site] = x.count("G") / maxind

print(pA)
print(pC)
print(pG)
print(pT)
```

Then one can use Numpy tools like fancy slicing

```
from __future__ import division

import os
import re
import sys

import numpy

from Bio import SeqIO


def parse_id(string_id):
    return tuple(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', string_id)))

def main():
    filename = sys.argv[1]

    data = list(SeqIO.parse(filename, "fasta"))
    header_keys = numpy.array([parse_id(datum.id) for datum in data])

    maxit, maxpop, maxind, maxlocus = header_keys.max(axis=0) + 1
    maxsite = len(data[0].seq)

    all = numpy.full((maxit, maxpop, maxind, maxlocus, maxsite), '\0', dtype="S")

    for header_key, sequence in zip(header_keys, data):
        all[tuple(header_key)] = sequence


    #### Calculate the frequencies ####
    pA = numpy.full((maxit, maxpop, maxsite), 2)
    pC = numpy.full((maxit, maxpop, maxsite), 2)
    pG = numpy.full((maxit, maxpop, maxsite), 2)
    pT = numpy.full((maxit, maxpop, maxsite), 2)

    for locus in xrange(maxlocus):
        for site in xrange(maxsite):
            x = all[..., locus, :]
            pA[...] = (x == "A").mean(axis=-2)
            pT[...] = (x == "T").mean(axis=-2)
            pC[...] = (x == "C").mean(axis=-2)
            pG[...] = (x == "G").mean(axis=-2)

    print(pA)
    print(pC)
    print(pG)
    print(pT)

main()
```

Note that

```
for site in xrange(maxsite):
```

is pointless as you don't use `site` and the effect is idempotent. Note then that

```
for locus in xrange(maxlocus):
    x = all[..., locus, :]
    pA[...] = (x == "A").mean(axis=-2)
    pT[...] = (x == "T").mean(axis=-2)
    pC[...] = (x == "C").mean(axis=-2)
    pG[...] = (x == "G").mean(axis=-2)
```

is just

```
x = all[..., -1, :]
pA[...] = (x == "A").mean(axis=-2)
pT[...] = (x == "T").mean(axis=-2)
pC[...] = (x == "C").mean(axis=-2)
pG[...] = (x == "G").mean(axis=-2)
```

Then one can skip the pre-initialization (`pA = numpy.full(...)`) and just do

```
x = all[..., -1, :]
pA = (x == "A").mean(axis=-2)
pT = (x == "T").mean(axis=-2)
pC = (x == "C").mean(axis=-2)
pG = (x == "G").mean(axis=-2)
```

This allows removing even more of the code.

**intermission**

Don't use `all` as a variable name; it clashes with the built-in (same for `id`).

**finishing up**

I feel this is a bit awkward still, but it's nicer than before.

```
from __future__ import division

import os
import re
import sys

import numpy

from Bio import SeqIO


def parse_id(string_id):
    return tuple(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', string_id)))[:3]

def main():
    filename = sys.argv[1]

    data = list(SeqIO.parse(filename, "fasta"))
    header_keys = numpy.array([parse_id(datum.id) for datum in data])

    maxit, maxpop, maxind = header_keys.max(axis=0) + 1
    maxsite = len(data[0].seq)

    sequences = numpy.full((maxit, maxpop, maxind, maxsite), '\0', dtype="S")
    for header_key, sequence in zip(header_keys, data):
        sequences[tuple(header_key)] = sequence

    # Calculate frequencies
    pA = (sequences == "A").mean(axis=-2)
    pT = (sequences == "T").mean(axis=-2)
    pC = (sequences == "C").mean(axis=-2)
    pG = (sequences == "G").mean(axis=-2)

    print(pA)
    print(pC)
    print(pG)
    print(pT)

main()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is a great answer. +1 The locus variable has disappeared but it is pretty easy to put it back in your code by adding `maxlocus` in numpy.array and taking the `[:3]` off the `parse_id` function